# How to calculate the probablity of a specific streak in x attempts?

Tags: python

I'm a complete beginner to programming and this is my first question ever in here. :)

Currently going through Automate the Boring Stuff and I'm having trouble getting a solution for one of the exercises at the end of chapter 4. I should create a program first to run 10,000 times an experiment where I'd flip a coin randomly 100 times, and then to check for and calculate the % probability of 6 heads or tails in a row.

This is my current attempt. There is clearly something wrong as I'm returned a 0,01% whereas the "correct solution" should be around 1.5%. I know there's lots of questions on the exact same subject already but I'm more interested in knowing how can I improve my code and what's wrong with it rather than finding out completely different solutions.

```
import random

numberOfStreaks = 0

for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    list = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(100)]
    for i in list:
       if list[i] == list[i + 1] == list[i + 2] == list[i + 3]
        == list[i + 4] == list[i + 5]:
           numberOfStreaks += 1
print 'Chance of streak: %s%%' % (numberOfStreaks / 100)
```

What did I mess up?

Comment: I think your error is in the `i` variable of the for loop. When you do `for i in list` the i gets assigned to the element of the list, not the indices. So using `list[i]` is wrong. Try changing the for loop to: `for i in range(len(list)-5):`

Comment: You could use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to compute all the streaks in the list.  Then look for the presence of a streak with length >= 6.

Comment: to complete the answer I think at the end of your loop or near the end your list is going out of bounds. Because list[i+5] would be list [104] that does not exist.

Comment: Also I would add that the percentage calculation at the end is wrong... You should divide the `numberOfStreaks` by the number of experiments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually a couple of errors in your code:

- When you do `for i in list:` the `i` gets assigned to the element of the list, not the indices.
- If you go through the whole list you risk overflowing when you access `list[i+5]`
- If you find a streak of length 6 you should stop investingating that example and move to the next one (otherwise one example can be counted multiple times)
- The final percentage needs to be calculated as number_of_streaks divided by number_of_examples (multiplied by 100)

Also I would suggest you to avoid using keywords as variable names (like you did with `list`).

The following is a corrected version (using python3)

```py
import random

number_of_streaks = 0
number_of_experiments = 10000

for _ in range(number_of_experiments):
    lst = [random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(100)]
    for i in range(len(lst) - 5):
        if sum(lst[i : i + 6]) in (0, 6):
            number_of_streaks += 1
            break

print(f"Chance of streak: {number_of_streaks / number_of_experiments * 100:.2f}%")
```

It turns out that getting a streak of length 6 when flipping 100 coins is pretty likely (around 80%)

Comment: I like that you used an underscore instead of an variable in the for loop! Nice approach

Comment: Easy and concise - love it! Thank you!

Comment: @uselessmoniker Please mark the answer as helpful, since it helped you! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Sidefact:** You can use a `_` in Python to represent big numbers more easily. It's maybe intresting due the fact that you are new to python!

I asume that we are talking about the probability of hitting head or tail six times in a row. If so, you could achieve it like so:

```
streaks = 0
for attempt in range(10_000):
    attempt_outcome = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(100)]
    for i in range(len(attempt_outcome)-5):
        if sum(attempt_outcome[i:i+5]) == 0 or sum(attempt_outcome[i:i+5]) == 6:
            streaks +=1
            break
print("Probability: {}".format(streaks / 10_000))
```

This leads us to this output:

```
>>> Probability: 0.8095
```

This means that 80.95% of the 10.000 attempts have one or more streaks, which are longer than six.

---

**Note:** We are breaking the for loop after we found the first streak, because in our case we don't need the information if there were more than one streak in the attempt outcome. It would influence our calculation and lead to a wrong result.